Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
I am new to Spring Boot and i face issue i cannot resolve using internet by myself. I am trying to connect application to xampp localhost database and i get this issue, I added all necessary dependencies and here is my simple code:
Main class
package com.example.kilohokla;




@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.kilohokla")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.kilohokla"})
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(HelloApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
//      AccountsRepository accountsRepository = applicationContext.getBean(AccountsRepository.class);
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloApplication.class);
//
//      Accounts sampleUser = new Accounts();
//      sampleUser.setName("Sample");
//      sampleUser.setSurname("User");
//      sampleUser.setEmail("sample@example.com");
//      sampleUser.setPhoneNumber("123456789");
//      sampleUser.setPassword("password");
//      sampleUser.setLogin("sample");

        // Save the sample user to the database
//      accountsRepository.save(sampleUser);
        logger.info("Applicaton has launched succesfully");

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("login-view.fxml"));

        Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/kilohokla/fonts/Inter/Inter.ttf"), 32);
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Kilohokla");
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        applicationContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(HelloApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Repo:
@Repository
public interface AccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<Accounts, Long> {

    void save(Accounts account);
}

Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Accounts {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long accountID;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "permissionID")
    private Permissions permission;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String password;
    private String login;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamID")
    private Teams team;

Controller
@Controller
public class AccountsController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public AccountsController() {
    }

    @PostMapping("/addAccount")
    public String addAccount(Accounts account) {
        accountService.addAccount(account);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}

Service:
@Service
public class AccountService {
    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepository accountsRepository;
    @Transactional
    public void addAccount(Accounts account) {
        accountsRepository.saveAndFlush(account);
    }
}

pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

i tried all solutions sugested by spingBoot documentation, stack posts and yt videos, i just want app to start ;(

Can you supply more information - how do you build the project, how do you run it and what is in the log

It is difficult to guess without logs but, jakarta.persistence-api is replacement for javax.persistence-api. So try removing javax.persistence-api from you pom.xml
